# Sharepoint 2010 - Update status list item by custom field not by ID

Tags: list, web, update, services

I have small list inside SharePoint 2010 site.

This list contains following columns:

[image]

I also created script which is able to Web Services to add new item or perform update.

What I know, the update may be performed only based on ID field, but the problem is that instead of ID, I would like to use CaseNumber# field.

So if CaseNumber# is 12345678 then update record 1

This is portion of my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sharePointURL, listName, batch, response, request, oXmlHTTP, domainName, domainUserName, domainPassword

domainName = "domainname"
domainUserName = "username"
domainPassword = "password"

set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

sharePointURL = "http://sharepointsite.com/sites/testsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" '?WSDL

listName = "TestList"

'the caml
batch = ""
batch = batch + " "
batch = batch + "  18"
batch = batch + "  1a1a1a"
batch = batch + "  1a.pdf"
batch = batch + "  Updated"
batch = batch + " "
batch = batch + ""

'soap wrapper plus some info in body
request =  ""
request =  request + ""
request =  request + "  "
request =  request + "  "
request =  request + "              " & Trim(listName) & ""
request =  request + "              " & Trim(batch) & ""
request =  request + "  "
request =  request + "  "
request =  request + ""

' build customer API request call using POST'
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", sharePointURL, False, domainName &"\"& domainUserName, domainpassword

oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"

oXmlHTTP.send Trim(request)

response = oXmlHTTP.responseText


Set oXmlHTTP = Nothing
```

Could You please tell me how to update list item based on CaseNumber and not using ID?

Thanks

Comment: You Need to get the list item and its ID by filtering list item based on `CaseNumber` and then update list item using the ID. you have to use ID for updating list item.

Comment: Can You tell me how? I am totally new in SharePoint

Comment: Ok I solved my problem by INVOKING GetListItems() web service methood before my another script to update items. I am parsing response and obtainins ows_ID field which is required for update. Later adding this dictionary with CaseNumber key and perform update.

Comment: Great. Glad the approach worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ID for updating list item.

Try following approach:

1. First of all get the list item and its ID by filtering list item based on CaseNumber.
2. Then update list item using the ID.

Comment: Hey, As this approach worked for you. Can you please accept it as a answer so that it will not be shown under Unanswered question section and it will get closed.